# EF entity with local file reference, transactional integrity

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I have EF entity that has a reference to local file. I'd like:

- file to be created/updated/removed along with entity
- file changes rollback to take place along with database operation rollback (by using of temporary backups, for example)

Is there any working solution for this? Wouldn't like to do my own :(

Answer (score 0):

using migrations there is an "up" and a "down" method that get called whenever a version is applied or rolled back. fairly sure you can write whatever code you want in that method.